# Python Pandas Dataframe from API JSON Response >>

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I am new to Python, Can i please seek some help from experts here?

I wish to construct a dataframe from https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/summaries JSON response.
based on following filter criteria

1. Kraken listed currency pairs (Please take note, there are kraken-futures i dont want those)
2. Currency paired with USD only, i.e aaveusd, adausd....

Ideal Dataframe i am looking for is (somehow excel loads this json perfectly screenshot below)
[Dataframe_Excel_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRnKu.png)

`resp = requests.get(https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/summaries) kraken_assets = resp.json() df = pd.json_normalize(kraken_assets) print(df)`

Output:

result.binance-us:aaveusd.price.last  result.binance-us:aaveusd.price.high  ...
0                                264.48                                267.32  ...

[1 rows x 62688 columns]

When i just paste the link in browser JSON response is with double quotes ("), but when i get it via python code. All double quotes (") are changed to single quotes (') any idea why?. Though I tried to solve it with json_normalize but then response is changed to [1 rows x 62688 columns]. i am not sure how do i even go about working with 1 row with 62k columns. i dont know how to extract exact info in the dataframe format i need (please see excel screenshot).

Any help is much appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the result JSON is a **dict**
- load this into a dataframe
- decode columns into products & measures
- filter to required data

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# load results into a data frame
df = pd.json_normalize(requests.get("https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/summaries").json()["result"])

# columns are encoded as product and measure.  decode columns and transpose into rows that include product and measure
cols = np.array([c.split(".", 1) for c in df.columns]).T
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(cols, names=["product","measure"])
df = df.T

# finally filter down to required data and structure measures as columns
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values("product").str[:7]=="kraken:"].unstack("measure").droplevel(0,1)
```

#### sample output

| product | price.last | price.high | price.low | price.change.percentage | price.change.absolute | volume | volumeQuote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kraken:aaveaud | 347.41 | 347.41 | 338.14 | 0.0274147 | 9.27 | 1.77707 | 613.281 |
| kraken:aavebtc | 0.008154 | 0.008289 | 0.007874 | 0.0219326 | 0.000175 | 403.506 | 3.2797 |
| kraken:aaveeth | 0.1327 | 0.1346 | 0.1327 | -0.00673653 | -0.0009 | 287.113 | 38.3549 |
| kraken:aaveeur | 219.87 | 226.46 | 209.07 | 0.0331751 | 7.06 | 1202.65 | 259205 |
| kraken:aavegbp | 191.55 | 191.55 | 179.43 | 0.030559 | 5.68 | 6.74476 | 1238.35 |
| kraken:aaveusd | 259.53 | 267.48 | 246.64 | 0.0339841 | 8.53 | 3623.66 | 929624 |
| kraken:adaaud | 1.61792 | 1.64602 | 1.563 | 0.0211692 | 0.03354 | 5183.61 | 8366.21 |
| kraken:adabtc | 3.757e-05 | 3.776e-05 | 3.673e-05 | 0.0110334 | 4.1e-07 | 252403 | 9.41614 |
| kraken:adaeth | 0.0006108 | 0.00063 | 0.0006069 | -0.0175326 | -1.09e-05 | 590839 | 367.706 |
| kraken:adaeur | 1.01188 | 1.03087 | 0.977345 | 0.0209986 | 0.020811 | 1.99104e+06 | 1.98693e+06 |

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try the below code. I have understood the structure of the Dataset and modified to get the desired output.
`

```
resp = requests.get("https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/summaries")
a=resp.json()
a['result']
#creating Dataframe froom key=result
da=pd.DataFrame(a['result'])
#using Transpose to get required Columns and Index
da=da.transpose()
#price columns contains a dict which need to be seperate Columns on the data frame
db=da['price'].to_dict()
da.drop('price', axis=1, inplace=True)
#intialising seperate Data frame for price
z=pd.DataFrame({})
for i in db.keys():
    i=pd.DataFrame(db[i], index=[i])
    z=pd.concat([z,i], axis=0 )
da=pd.concat([z, da], axis=1)
da.to_excel('nex.xlsx')`
```